# Встраивание JS кода/файла в представление в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Изучаю php, попутно Yii2 и JS. Столкнулся с проблемой: пытаюсь в вид добавить JS код, используя методы `$this->registerJs()` и `$this->registerJSFile()` для файла .js; но ничего не происходит и не подключается. Возможно я упускаю какие-то основы?

Фрагмент кода из вида:

```
$this->registerJs(<<<JS
    alert('Alert');
JS);
$this->registerJsFile(
    '@web/js/message.js'
);
```

Метод в контроллере:

```
public function actionMessage(): string
    {
        $user = Yii::$app
            ->user
            ->getIdentity();

        if ($user === null) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        $path = Yii::$app
            ->request
            ->getPathInfo();
        preg_match('/\d+/', $path, $matches);

        if (empty($matches)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        $id = (int)$matches[0];
        $message = Message::find()
            ->byId($id)
            ->one();
        $username = $user->getUsername();
        $userIsSender = $message->getSenderUsername() === $username;

        if (!$userIsSender && $message->getRecipientUsername() !== $username) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        return $this->render('message', ['message' => $message, 'userIsSender' => $userIsSender]);
    }
```

Правило маршрута выглядит так:

```
'profile/message/<action:\d+>' => 'profile/message'
```

Пример URL: http://localhost/profile/message/1

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что не подключается?

Comment: Мой совет: никогда не использовать  ни `registerJs` ни `registerJsFile` это ужасно и получается каша из js и php и html.... Пишите код js в обычных файлах js, а подключение необходимых файлов в представление можно сделать через ассет ( https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets )  .... Через ассеты даже проще будет контролировать что где подключено

Comment: а если хочется делать мешанину, js код можно писать тоже как обычно: просто в теге `<script>`

Comment: To: [Roman Grinyov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201026/roman-grinyov) Банальный alert не вызывается и в списке загруженных файлов нет подключаемого файла (плюс функции объявленные в файле сайт не находит)
To: [Алексей Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%a8%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9) Не будет ли лишним создавать ассет, если файл JS подключается только в одном конкретном виде?

Comment: Чтобы упомнять кого-то можно поставить @  вначале и начать писать ник........... имхо - всё нормально. с ассетами больше контроля. тем более они хорошо кэшируются, а подключение файла не уверен. ассеты чуть более гибкие в настроках могут быть и могут быть сделаны предварительные  инициализационные операции...найти потом проще какие ассеты где подключены, а вот в каком виде подключен скрипт чуть сложнее. ну это лишь моё имхо...по опыту работы с yii2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для корректной работы функций `$this->registerJs()` и `$this->registerJsFile()` требовалось установить маркеры в шаблон типа `$this->endBody()` и ему подобные. Как всегда надо внимательнее читать документацию и желательно с самых азов.